What is meant by ' total darkness' in Proverbs 20:20?
We read in Proverbs 20:20 (AMP):

Whoever curses his father or his mother,
His lamp [of life] will be extinguished in time of darkness.

The phrase ' of life'. given in parenthesis is not seen in other Versions , which otherwise qualify'darkness' with terms like 'total ' and ' acute'. For instance:

Whoso curseth his father or his mother, his lamp shall be put out in the blackest darkness.(DARBY)

The term 'light going out' looks like a euphemism for death. But what is meant by the saying ' in total darkness '? Does it stand for the nadir of life? Or, does it refer to the time when the light is in full flame that is, life is at its prime? How do Bible scholars interpret the term?
PS: A question of October, 2018 on the topic already exists on BHE. I am looking for some new perspectives. Please bear with me. See Pupil/eye, or light/ lamp, or "time of darkness" in Proverbs 20 verse 20?

The "PS" should contain a link to the other question.

@RayButterworth It is the 4th one down on the list of "Related" questions, on the right-hand-side of this page. One click will get you there.

@Anne that's subject to change at any time.

@hobbs  True, but so far, so good. And that's 17 hours from the Q being asked. Forgive me if I sound exasperated here (I actually am.) But these days people expect everything to be handed to them on a digital plate. "Click this link" - instant info. Finding a book and reading for oneself the exact bit needed, giving a book source reference, is so looked down on. No matter that digital info might be so A.I. generated that it misleads, being accepted unquestioningly as a fount of all knowledge, then Christians will end up drawn away from the actual written word of God. Ah, I feel better now.

Well- said Anne. One wonders how people remembered and quoted Bible Verses before they would be numbered !

@Anne, I think it's more a matter of expecting the OP to do due diligence, and NOT relying on "everything being handed to them" by the automated and inaccurate list of "(un)Related questions."

Any Bible version that is "Amplified" gives the clue as to why some clarity is provided. By adding words (indicated by square brackets around [of life]) shows the translator adding what is not actually in the Hebrew text, to suggest what is meant. It is a form of inserting an interpretation.
Literal translations do their best to avoid doing that, only adding in square brackets word that they feel are needed (in English) to make grammatical sense of the sentence. Here is a literal translation of the verse in question:

"Whoso is vilifying his father and his mother, extinguished is his
lamp in blackness of darkness." Young's Literal Translation

Hebrew readers in that era would not need any explanatory additions provided, for they knew the Hebrew scriptures that commanded such a grossly disrespectful, disobedient grown-up son to be stoned to death (Deuteronomy 21:18-21). Exodus 20:12 & Deuteronomy 5:16 has the law inscribed in stone, to honour one's mother and father "that your days may be prolonged". There is not a shadow of doubt but that Proverbs 20:20 warned of that one's life being extinguished.
As for "total darkness / blackest darkness", as in other translations, this phrase crops up in the New Testament (in Greek) in Jude verse 13. Of wicked men corrupting the Church of Christ it is said that they are,

"...wandering stars, to whom is reserved the blackness of darkness for
ever." (K.J.V.)

Jude's warning of death that leads to blackest darkness is also connected to an eternal state. In Proverbs it does not say that, but the horror of darkness implied is reminiscent of other places in the Hebrew scriptures where supernatural darkness enveloped some, briefly. Clearly, Proverbs 20:20 is using the strongest possible language to warn against anyone cursing their parents.

Up-voted +1. The OT could not speak of 'eternity' (yet) as Christ was not yet come who would fulfil all and 'bring life and immortality to light in the gospel'. Gehenna, the lake of fire, and eternal punishment are revealed in the gospel, not before it.

What does 'Total Darkness' mean in Prov.20:20
Let me use this version:

“Whoso curseth his father or his mother, his lamp shall be put out in obscure darkness.” (Pro 20:20, KJV)

The fundamental background to this verse is Lev.20:9:

“For every one that curseth his father or his mother shall be surely put to death: he hath cursed his father or his mother; his blood shall be upon him.” (Lev 20:9, KJV)

This death is physical. Ex.21:17. Hence his 'lamp' is extinguished by the death penalty. Jesus referred to this in Matt.15:4 but the full context is elucidated from verses 1 to 9. The context is one of many ways a father and mother may be cursed.
If Prov.20:20 is used parallel to Lev. 20:9, we can safely conclude that 'his lamp shall be put out' means death, that is, physical death. This death means such will leave this world in a gruesome manner as a judgment. Such does not deserve to transact business and continue in the world. Hence, he is sent out of this world.
Since he left this world as God's commanded judgement, where he is outside of this earthly life would be referred to as 'Total Darkness' or 'Obscure Darkness' according to the KJV version.
I see a comparison of two places here: this earthly life vs the world outside of this world referred to as 'obscure darkness'
The Hebrew word translated as 'obscure' is אישׁון and it carries two meanings:

pupil of the eye
middle of the night (that is the deepest blackness)

The word 'obscure' describes the extremity of the darkness the guilty one will find himself. Hence 'obscure darkness' can be translated as 'blackness of darkness'.
This brings a question to the front burner:
What if the curse was not a physical action unlike as referenced by Jesus in Matt.15:1-9? Or what if his 'lamp' is not put out by the death penalty as in the case of corruption exercised by the scribes and Pharisees (Matt 15:1-9), has the guilty one escaped Prov.20:20?
A scripture readily rings a bell:

“The eye that mocketh at his father, and despiseth to obey his mother, the ravens of the valley shall pick it out, and the young eagles shall eat it.” (Pro 30:17, KJV)

I see a glimpse of possible effects even if there is no physical death; he will not see. The light of nature will be taken away from him.
Giving it a spiritual connotation: His 'eyes' will not be able to perceive and be effective in this world. This is a kind of 'blackness of darkness'.
Conclusion:
Hence, aside from physical death which leads to total separation from this world, if he escapes death, his navigation via perception cannot be the same again.
Spiritually, his spiritual eyes of understanding will malfunction. Eph.1:18
The state of the result of cut-off from the vitals of life in this world either physical or spiritual is 'Total Darkness'.

The Hebrew word חֹ֫שֶׁך (choshek = "darkness") is an important word as it is used both literally and metaphorically for confusion and spiritual darkness.  The same is true of the words "light" and "lamp" in the opposite sense - both signify (metaphorically) spiritual enlightenment.
The metaphorical meaning is that used in Prov 20:20 and is consistent with numerous other such uses in the OT such as:

Job 10:20-22 - Are my days not few? Withdraw from me, that I may have a little comfort, before I go—never to return— to a land of darkness and gloom, to a land of utter darkness, of deep shadow and disorder, where even the light is like darkness.”
Job 12:24, 25 - He deprives the earth’s leaders of reason and makes them wander in a trackless wasteland. They grope in the darkness without light; He makes them stagger like drunkards.
Ps 18:28 - For You, O LORD, light my lamp; my God lights up my darkness.
Ps 119:105 - Your word is a lamp to my feet and a light to my path.
Prov 2:11-14 - Discretion will watch over you, and understanding will guard you, to deliver you from the way of evil, from the man who speaks perversity, from those who leave the straight paths to walk in the ways of darkness, from those who enjoy doing evil and rejoice in the twistedness of evil,
Prov 13:9 - The light of the righteous shines brightly, but the lamp of the wicked is extinguished.
Eccl 2:13 - And I saw that wisdom exceeds folly, just as light exceeds darkness:
Isa 9:2 - The people who walked in darkness have seen a great light; those who dwelt in a land of deep darkness, on them has light shone.
Isa 60:2 - For behold, darkness covers the earth, and thick darkness is over the peoples; but the LORD will rise upon you, and His glory will appear over you.
Lam 3:2 - He has driven me away and made me walk in darkness instead of light.

Note that passages like the prophecy is Isa 9:2, 60:2 were fulfilled by Jesus who said:

John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.”
John 1:4, 5 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men. 5The Light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.
John 1:9 - The true Light who gives light to every man was coming into the world.

Proverbs 20:20

Whoever curses his father or mother, his lamp will be extinguished in
deepest darkness.

See also Prov 13:9 above.
Thus Proverbs 20:20 is discussing spiritual light and spiritual darkness and teaches that disrespect of parental authority (ie, breaking the fifth commandment) bring spiritual darkness and obscurity.  The pulpit commentary expresses this well:

Verse 20. - This is an enforcement of the fifth commandment, by
denouncing the punishment which the moral government of God shall
exact from the unnatural child. The legal penalty may be seen (Exodus
21:17; Leviticus 20:9); but this was probably seldom or never carried
into execution (comp. Matthew 15:4; Mark 7:10). His lamp shall be put
out in obscure (the blackest) darkness (comp. Proverbs 13:9). The
expression is peculiar; it is literally, according to the Khetib, In
the apple of the eye of darkness, as in Proverbs 7:9; i.e. in the very
centre of darkness; he will find himself surrounded on all sides by
midnight darkness, without escape, with no hope of Divine protection.
"Lamp" is a metaphor applied to the bodily and the spiritual life, to
happiness and prosperity, to a man's fame and reputation, to a man's
posterity; and all these senses may be involved in the denunciation of
the disobedient and stubborn child. He shall suffer in body and soul,
in character, in fortune, in his children. His fate is the exact
counterpart of the blessing promised in the Law. Septuagint, "The lamp
of him that revileth father and mother shall be extinguished, and the
pupils of his eyes shall behold darkness." Talmud, "Whosoever abandons
his parents means his body to become the prey of scorpions." Cato,
'Dist.,' 3:23 -


Thanks, Dottard for the scholarly inputs . One can see you delving deep into the subject and compiling all the available references. But my humble suggestion is that for the purpose of brevity,  you include only those quotes which have a significant say on the topic.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - that is what I did - the best Bible hermeneutic is to use the patterns of bible evidence and not "Cafeteria theology" where one just chooses the Bible texts that suit a pre-conceived idea.

Thanks, Dottard. I think I got an answer for why the word ' abbreviation' is longer than ' elongation ' !
